# Writing to excel documents with an android app

Tags: java, android

So this is probably a dumb question but can an android app that runs on an android device write to excel documents using apache poi? I havent been able to find any tutorials online that say specifically. I have found java tutorials that make a simple workbook and it creates a xls document just fine. if i put that same code into an android application i get

```
11-18 23:02:10.311: D/AndroidRuntime(12615): Shutting down VM
11-18 23:02:10.311: W/dalvikvm(12615): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41643d40)
11-18 23:02:10.314: E/AndroidRuntime(12615): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-18 23:02:10.314: E/AndroidRuntime(12615): Process: com.example.prtmanager, PID: 12615
11-18 23:02:10.314: E/AndroidRuntime(12615): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.prtmanager/com.example.prtmanager.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.prtmanager.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
11-18 23:02:10.314: E/AndroidRuntime(12615):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
11-18 23:02:10.314: E/AndroidRuntime(12615):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
11-18 23:02:10.314: E/AndroidRuntime(12615):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
11-18 23:02:10.314: E/AndroidRuntime(12615):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
11-18 23:02:10.314: E/AndroidRuntime(12615):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-18 23:02:10.314: E/AndroidRuntime(12615):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-18 23:02:10.314: E/AndroidRuntime(12615):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
11-18 23:02:10.314: E/AndroidRuntime(12615):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-18 23:02:10.314: E/AndroidRuntime(12615):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-18 23:02:10.314: E/AndroidRuntime(12615):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
11-18 23:02:10.314: E/AndroidRuntime(12615):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
11-18 23:02:10.314: E/AndroidRuntime(12615):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-18 23:02:10.314: E/AndroidRuntime(12615): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.prtmanager.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
11-18 23:02:10.314: E/AndroidRuntime(12615):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1084)
11-18 23:02:10.314: E/AndroidRuntime(12615):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2126)
11-18 23:02:10.314: E/AndroidRuntime(12615):    ... 11 more
```

**class**

```
 package com.example.prtmanager;

 import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
 import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

 import java.io.FileOutputStream;

 public class MainActivity {

 public static void main(String[] args){
    Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();

    try {
        FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("Test.xls");
        workbook.write(output);
        output.close();
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
 }
```

Comment: nothing to do with POI.  This code is no an Android app.

Comment: So my next question is can android apps do this?

Comment: @dtrodriguez Where is your launcher activity.

Comment: @dtrodriguez yes you can do this in android app.

Comment: @dtrodriguez at the time of application open,which class will open first.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you do it in Android, no main function. OnCreate is kind of main function here, now all you need to do is to make this `functionFile()` work.

```
public class Sample extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        functionFile();
    }

    public void functionFile() {
        Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();

        try {
            File file = new File("");
            FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("Test.xls");
            workbook.write(output);
            output.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

You seem to be new to Android, read more [How to make activities.](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html)